# cannot run virtual box on windows 10 enterprise technique preview

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-10

I was using VirtualBox 4.3.20r96997 on Windows 10 Enterprise Techinque Preview with version build 9841 and everything works fine.But when I update the system to build 9926 I cannot start the VirtualBox.There is no response when I try to run virtualbox.exe.

I tried to run VBoxSDL.exe in command line, I got the error

> : RTLdrOpenWithReader failed: Unknown Status -626 (0xfffffd8e) (Image='\SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll').

And when I try to run a virtual machine in command line,I got

> Waiting for VM "xp" to power on...
>
> VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'xp' has terminated unexpectedly
>
> during startup with exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)
>
> VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component Machine, interface IMachine

Comment: try the new version 4.3.22. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Comment: I had a similar issue with DRM Fasoo installed in this MS Windows10 machine. After solving many other issues, I just reinstalled the last virtualbox version (5.2.22) as last operation and it solved this error code and ran the VM like a charm :-)